# WSO2 API Manager - Handle Authentication failure with Custom Authenticator

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm implementing a custom Authentication Handler for wso2-am following this guide https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Writing+Custom+Handlers
But it's not clear how to handle the case when my authentication handler returns false. The sample code of the handleRequest is

```
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {
    try {
        if (authenticate(messageContext)) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (APISecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I try calling an API with valid credentials everything goes well (the method returns true) and I get an "HTTP 200 OK" response. If I try with invalid credentials the method returns false but I get an HTTP 202 ACCEPTED" response. I would like to receive another response code (for example 400). How do I handle this authentication failure path?

Thank you.

Comment: You can definitely can handle the failure scenario. Have a look at [1] which handle the throttle out scenario of API Manager within the handler.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/release-1.10.x/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/APIThrottleHandler.java#L210-L263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you need to call handleAuthFaliure method with message context.

```
private void handleAuthFailure(MessageContext messageContext, APISecurityException e)
```

When you call that method please create APISecurityException object(as listed below) and pass it. Then error code and error messages will be picked from there and automatically send error to client(by default we return 401 for security exceptions and if defined then send defined error code and message).

```
public class APISecurityException extends Exception {
    private int errorCode;
    public APISecurityException(int errorCode, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public APISecurityException(int errorCode, String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks

sanjeewa.